# How get Xpath of attribute value in tag?

Tags: xml, xpath

Could someone provide an example of how to get XPath of the attribute value of tag "ggl:h1"?
The result must be "456".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site xmlns:ggl="http://ggl"> 
    <ggl:header> 
        <ggl:h value="987"/> 
        <ggl:h1 value="456"/>
        <ggl:h2 value="321"/> 
    </ggl:header> 
</site>
```

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: @JaSON I tried /site/ggl:header/ggl:h1/@value. But I catch an error about "Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation"

Comment: Try `/site/*[local-name()='header']/*[local-name()='h1']/@value`